# Is it safe to send merchant PayPal's "Receipt for Your Payment "?

Tags: paypal, security

In purchasing on-line from a small store, using PayPal, the seller sent me an E-mail saying, to prevent fraud, they need me to send a screenshot of the E-mail "Receipt for Your Payment" from PayPal, otherwise they must cancel my order. Is it safe to provide these details to the seller?

Note that PayPal never contacted me about any problems. But the company persists I send this or they won't let me order. Is there any details in the receipt the shop could use for fraud against me?

Comment: Maybe the fraud they are trying to prevent is a hijacked PayPal account.

Comment: That isn't (or shouldn't be) something the store should have to deal with. If it is, it's another reason not to accept PayPal in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any reason it wouldn't be safe, as long as you are sure that you are sending the screenshot to the seller, and not someone else. As far as I know there shouldn't be any information contained in that email that the seller would not already have access to. That being said, my assumption is that the only information the seller needs in order to verify you are the person that made the payment, is the PayPal Transaction ID. For good measure, you might as well also include the date and time, amount paid, and your name.

If you see anything else in the screenshot that you don't think they already know, and you wouldn't want them to know, then I think you'd be fine to cross it out. (Surely they'll let you know if they have a problem with that!)

Comment: Snipping Tool FTW!!  It's built into Windows (I think), and lets you just grab that portion that you want.

Comment: Shift-Windows-S

Answer (score -1):

It’s a scam! Only send the transaction ID never a screenshot. They can use it against you to make a claim they never received the item from you, even though you are supposed to be receiving the item. Scam. What happened?

Comment: Why would the seller make a claim on behalf of the buyer to refund the money to the buyer at the expense of the seller? What?